# Change cursor to hand over certain co-ordinates in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, cursor, jframe

I have a boolean that changes when the mouse is within the set co-ordinates inside the JFrame and then I have an if in my run method so that I can change the cursor but I cannot find anywhere of how to change the cursor without using a list or object. How would I change the cursor without using an object other than JFrame?

Comment: *"How would I change the cursor without using an object other than JFrame?"*  Why 'without an object'?  This seems like a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/155831).

Comment: what I have is just a mouseListener in the JFrame that when I click in a certain area I have some code that changes something but I need to figure out how to change the mouse to a hand in those areas

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to 'not' use other objects/components. Some example code, showing what you've tried might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure why you would need to 'not' use other objects. If you were willing to use something like a `JPanel`, your code could become very simple. For example, you could add a `JPanel` to the area in question, and then set a cursor to recognize each time the cursor entered or left that swing component. For example;

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;


public class ExampleClass{    

    public static void main(String args[]){

        JFrame exampleFrame = new JFrame("Test");          
        exampleFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        exampleFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        exampleFrame.setSize(300, 300);

        JPanel redPanel = new JPanel();
        redPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        redPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 300));
        redPanel.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR)); // This one line changes the cursor.

        exampleFrame.add(redPanel);
        exampleFrame.setVisible(true);            
    }
}
```

Although it is entirely possible to do what your asking, it sounds as though it would be much more verbose/less readable than is necessary to see results. The `JPanel` wouldn't even need to be a different color, it could be completely invisible to the user (`redPanel.setOpaque(false);` would do the trick).

Running the example code above shows a `JFrame` with a centralized red square (the `JPanel` redPanel). Moving your mouse over the red square changes the cursor.

---

If for some reason the above method is impractical or your program design is very much set in it's ways, you could use absolute co-ordinates relative to your `JFrame`. Create a `MouseMotionListener` for your JFrame, like so;

```
class CursorMouseMotionListener implements MouseMotionListener{

    JFrame yourFrame;

    CursorMouseMotionListener(JFrame yourFrame){
        this.yourFrame = yourFrame;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
    /// The important bit below
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        if(e.getPoint().x >= 50 && e.getPoint().x <=150 && e.getPoint().y >= 50 && e.getPoint().y <=150){
            yourFrame.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        }
        else{
            yourFrame.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR));
        }
    }

}
```

Then add this to your JFrame like so;

```
frame.addMouseMotionListener(new CursorMouseMotionListener(frame));
```

You will have to change the coordinates, of course, to match the position of your buttons but then your good. I still wouldn't advise this method if you can avoid it. Better to use the swing components at your disposal. But if you absolutely need to with your current program then this should work.

Comment: The reason was because I already have around 1000 lines of code in that class and I am using co-ordinates as buttons

Comment: @silverlight513 - I'm assuming your using one image as a background for the frame, which includes the button appearances etc. If your already able to check the mouse position and whether it is already over the button then all you need to do is set the `Cursor` for the frame `if` your within those areas `else` keep the normal one using `frame.setCursor();`. I've edited my question to include an alternative you can probably use.

Comment: That is exactly what I was doing and looking for, thanks a lot.